# open vimeo url in colorbox using jQuery filter

Tags: jquery, regex, embed, vimeo

I would like to use jQuery to scan a html page - created in this case by WordPress to find all links to vimeo vidoes - added by users via the WP editing admin.

I would then like to pass control of these links to colorbox.

The jQuery selector works with this link:

http://vimeo.com/44799432

```
// vimeo in colorbox ##
jQuery("a").filter(function(){ // filter all as ##
    return jQuery(this).text().match(/vimeo\.com/igm); // match text with vimeo.com ##
    }).colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth: "80%", innerHeight: "80%"}) // assign to colorbox ##
    .addClass("button vimeo"); // add class to style ##
```

However, vimeo pushes the content out of the iframe and reloads the page - so I need a regex that will match this url - that can be embedded via an iframe:

http://player.vimeo.com/video/44799432

```
match(/player.vimeo\.com/);
```

does not do it - any ideas?

NOTE: I'll obviously need a loop to check for multiple vimeo links...

Thanks!

Comment: ok - so I just learnt something about how SOF works - and now have 100% rate - thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one *(untested)* >>

```
jQuery("a").filter(function() {
    return jQuery(this).text().match(/vimeo\.com/igm);
  }).each(function() { 
    this.setAttribute("href", this.getAttribute("href")
    .replace(/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.|)vimeo\.com\/(\d+)$/i,
      "http://player.vimeo.com/video/$1")); 
  }).colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth: "80%", innerHeight: "80%"})
  .addClass("button vimeo");
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't see the relevance.. in the end I've used oembed as that might just be easier, but currently seems to require the shortcode in WP... but it works.

Comment: @QLStudio - I am not sure if we are clear what exactly you want to parse. I believed you are trying to find out redirection url from short url version to long one and the above answer comes with solution. If that is not what you want, you should clarify your question by editing it with more details and/or examples.